# Merge multiple polygon shapefile to a single polygon shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18

I'm looking to merge all internal polygons in a gridded shapefile to one solid polygon shapefile while retaining the external shape.

[image: Shapefile image for visualization]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

You can probably just start an edit session, select all (drag a box), and choose the Merge Selected Features button.

[image: Merge Selected]

[image: Merged polygons]

Comment: Merge Selected Features button shows grey??

Answer (score 0):

Togle edit the layer you would like to merge, select all features then merge as shown on the previous answer, NB: activate the advanced digitizing toolbar in your menu bar.